# Is it possible to convert caffe model to coreml using coremltools 5.2 and python 3.10.4

Tags: python-3.x, caffe, coreml, coremltools

I can't find a way to convert a caffe model to a CoreMl format using CoreMltools 5.2 and python 3.10.4

I'm aware that it was possible using an older version of CoreMltools and python 2.7